# Wifi adapter is a installed but still I can't see my available wifi networks

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

I have Ubuntu 23.04 but I have had this problem since Ubuntu 22.04. My wifi adapter is working fine. The problem is it's scanning visible networks and keeps loading and just showing the loading screen of visible networks. It is not showing visible networks. [I have uploaded the screenshot of my wifi loading screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbxni.png)

Comment: What does the command `nmcli dev wifi` tell you?

Comment: On entering nmcli dev wifi command it shows nothing.